# Which version of scala has the case class limit of 22 elements lifted?

Tags: scala

The following merge shows that the case class limit was lifted. But in which version of scala does that appear?

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2305

[image]

Comment: I think it was fixed in 2.11 according to Jira

Comment: saw that .. but it was my impression it were not available in 2.11. While I *could* try to test it - that might not catch some non-obvious corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "Milestone" on the right, you can see that it was merged under `2.11.0-M3`, meaning this was fixed in 2.11.0 and above:

[image]

You can also verify this using `git log --pretty=oneline v2.11.0-M2...v2.11.0-M3` which shows all the commits between these two tags:

[image]